# Initial Value Problem Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the problem:

For the differential equation

$y'=$exp$(x−y)$

find the solution for the initial value problem $y(0)=0$.

I tried to plug in 0 into the equation, which lead me nowhere - $0=exp(x)$.  What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the correct answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $y'\, e^y=e^x $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written as
$$
e^y \,dy=e^x \, dx
$$
Integrating we obtain
$$
e^y=e^x +c
$$
So, if $y(0)=0$ then $c=0$. Therefore $y=x$.

Comment: Oh, so you have to mess around with the $e$'s to get to the answer.  That definitely helps a lot, thank you.